# SUM UNION QUERY

Tags: sum, union, union-all

I have the below query for a UNION ALL. I just need to modify it so it will SUM the result.

```
select count (*)
from BAU_DEAN_USER 
where checked_date >= date '2019-03-01' and checked_date < date '2019-03-05'

UNION ALL

select count (*)
from BAU_DEAN_USER_ARCHIVE 
where checked_date >= date '2019-03-01' and
      checked_date < date '2019-03-05'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select count (*) from 
(select 'a' from
BAU_DEAN_USER where checked_date >= date '2019-03-01' and checked_date < date '2019-03-05'

UNION ALL

select 'a' from BAU_DEAN_USER_ARCHIVE where checked_date >= date '2019-03-01' and checked_date < date '2019-03-05')
```